# SKVideoNode with AVPlayer is playing but not visible on iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, ios9, skvideonode

I have a problem with Xcode 7.0 (7A220) and iOS 9.0. I add a video (.mp4 or mov, both not working) with an `AVPlayer` and `SKVideoNode`. On the simulator with iOS 8.4 it's working fine, but on iOS 9.0 (also simulator) the video is not showing. I can hear the audio though.

The code in my `GameScene` (of class `SKScene`):

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"VideoName" ofType:@"mp4"]];
    _player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL: fileURL];

    _videoNode = [[SKVideoNode alloc] initWithAVPlayer:_player];
    _videoNode.size = CGSizeMake(200, 100);
    _videoNode.position = CGPointMake(200, 200);
    _videoNode.zPosition = 1000;

    [self addChild:_videoNode];

    _player.volume = 0.5;
    [_videoNode play];
}
```

In the `UIViewController` I have this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    // I have set this to NO, but it doesn't help
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = NO;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    GameScene *videoScene = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:rect.size];
    videoScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    GameScene *scene = [GameScene unarchiveFromFile:@"GameScene"];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:videoScene];
}
```

So the app is not crashing, the video is playing (I can hear it), but the video is invisible on iOS 9 only. Does someone have an idea to fix it?

Comment: check the view hierarchy to see the frame of the player

Comment: @VarunNaharia I don't see anything in it, only the UIWindow and SKView. I don't think sprites are visible in it.

Comment: Use real devices, iOS 9 simulator doesn't display anything in SKVideoNode... And there are other annoying bugs too, like automatically starts playing...